# Python - directed edge list to dictionary of dictionaries

Tags: python, data-structures, dictionary, graph

I have a list of directed edges in a file in the form

```
Source_Id  Target_Id    Edge_Type
A          B            Train
A          C            Bus
B          D            Bus
C          A            Train
...        ...
```

I would like to structure the data in a dictionary of dictionaries such as:

```
{'A': {'B': 'Train', 'C': 'Bus'}, 'B': {'D': 'Bus'}, 'C': {'A': 'Train'}}
```

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [`collections.defaultdict()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) object to materialize the values for you:

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

graph = defaultdict(dict)

with open('inputfile', 'rb') as infh:
    reader = csv.reader(infh, delimiter='\t')
    next(reader, None)  # skip header

    for source, target, edge in reader:
        graph[source][target] = edge
```

This assumes there is only one edge between each source and target, and that the inputfile is tab delimited.

If there are multiple edges, build a list of edge names instead:

```
graph = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))

with open('inputfile', 'rb') as infh:
    reader = csv.reader(infh, delimiter='\t')
    next(reader, None)  # skip header

    for source, target, edge in reader:
        graph[source][target].append(edge)
```

giving you

```
{'A': {'C': ['Bus'], 'B': ['Train']}, 'C': {'A': ['Train']}, 'B': {'D': ['Bus']}}
```

where the edge lists can then represent more edge names.

Comment: Thanks! And what if I have more then one edge between the same nodes such as: A B bus  A B train. Is there a way?

Comment: @user3137076: Yes, use `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(list))` as the `graph`, and use `graph[source][target].append(edge)` to get a list of edges instead.